# Finding the column index of the last non zero cell in a set of certain cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

Is there any way that I can get the index of last none zero column in a set of certain columns (columns are not adjacent) in excel with out the use of VBA?

[image]

Comment: Why it is `C9`? Why not `C7` or `C13` or `....`?

Comment: Can you explain why you hightlighted column I **and** can you include what you tried yourself?

Comment: C3 , C6, C9, C12, C15 are the set of columns that I mentioned in my question. in fact I want a formula that pinpoints the in index of C9, witch is the last none zero column in that set of columns.

Answer (score 1):

In `S2`, enter formula :

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/N(OFFSET(A1,1,{2,5,8,11,14})),T(OFFSET(A1,0,{2,5,8,11,14})))
```

[image]